# How to set Flash Player window location in Flash project as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have 2 monitors on my computer, also am writing a program on `AS3` that is exported to standalone `SWF`. My task is to make my app fullscreen on 2nd screen. How can I do this?

I tried converting my project to `AIR` project. It is possible there by using `nativeWindow` property of `Stage`. (setting `x` coordinate so that it appears in second screen and then call fullscreen). It works in Flash, but when I'm running compiled `swf` outside Flash, my app crashes (nativeWindow property not found).

So please do help me to solve my problem. I am disappointed, have been looking for solution for already 3 days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stick with your AIR application and use it as it is supposed to: run the .air file. You can't launch an AIR swf alone because it will miss all the AIR runtime including the `NativeWindow` you are insterested in.

To be clear, you can't manipulate windows from a swf launched with the Flash Player.

Another solution would be to execute your swf from a web browser and use javascript called through `ExternalInterface` to move the windows. But it may be quite painful in comparison with AIR.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Kodiak. It should be standalone application... I will try to run my .airi file at the moment. One more question, is it possible to make a projector from it?

Comment: Well I don't know what you mean by projector, but once you have installed the air file, your application is available as a .exe file (or whatever is the executable format on your OS).